# How to change the reference in browser search field

Tags: php, html, apache

This is the html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="modules/registration/registration.php" method="POST">
            <input  type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the registration.php code:

```
<?php
    echo "<p>Registration is completed!</p>";
?>
```

If I push button all works as i need. But i wouldn't like show the internal folder structure. In browser search field it looks like on the picture below.

[image]

I would like that in the browser search field the reference looks like following:

[image]

This is the folder structure:

[image]

How can I do this? Thank you for any help.

Comment: using .htaccess you can do this..

Comment: Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using htaccess you can `Rewrite` the URL to delete folder url and show only registration.php.

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^modules/registration/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ modules/registration/$1 [L]
```

So the result will be

```
myurl.com/registration.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^registration.php modules/registration/registration.php
</IfModule>
```